# Memory exhausted when using AWS SDK

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using the AWS PHP SDK with my laravel app. I am not seeing issues with many of the API calls but when trying to retrieve a list of AMIs I am getting the following error.

`Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10365580 bytes)`

I know this is a php error and I can technically increase the memory, but I feel that shoudl not be neccessary. Below is the code I am using. is there something I can change to prevent this error?

```
   $ec2 = AWS::get('Ec2');
   $amis = $ec2->DescribeImages();
   print_r($amis);
```

I also tried adding filters but I get the same error. even when tryign to fetch 1 AMI.

is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: It is probably caused by AWS dependency to guzzle/guzzle. You should solve upgrading AWS to version 3

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `print_r` with `var_dump`. `print_r` will print everything **recursively**, which can eat your memory a lot.